# Refactor all getters / setters not to start with a leading get / set across entire Java codebase

Tags: java, linux, eclipse, refactoring, automated-refactoring

I'm looking for a suggestion on how to refactor a +50K lines of Java.

Inspired by [version 2.x of the AWS SDK for Java](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/latest/developer-guide/migration.html), which has many builders and almost no getters / setters that start with a leading get / set such as `getNum()`, `setNum(double x)`, etc. The shortened notation is very concise and formatters will definitely make many lines fit on one line.

The problem is that going one by one is cumbersome and error prone (even with finding all `get` / `set` occurrences). I tried to replace `getX` / `setX` alphabetically but this is still very cumbersome and error prone.

I'm working with Eclipse on Ubuntu, so any `sed`, `find`, etc. suggestions are welcome as well. Any suggestions on how to do this refactoring elegantly?

Comment: Firstly, getX and setX are THE standard. Secondly, you wouldn't be coding any getters or setters at all if you used [Lombok](https://projectlombok.org) (highly recommended).

Comment: I understand that not everyone likes the Java Beans way of doing things, i.e. set|(get|is), but a lot of automated tooling identifies rw and ro attributes using this convention. If you want a fluent interface, then that takes some effort. You have to know if you consider the change in style worth the effort. Using lombok to create builders is a similar way of doing things (@Builder) which requires minimal effort.

Comment: Eclipse has good support for multiline regex search and replace. Crtl+H should open the tool. Take some time to write a good regex and test it.

Comment: Not to mention, that with `get` and `set`, auto-complete is vastly superior: Looking for a simple reporting property that doesn't imply any actions or calculations? Just type `.get`, hit CMD+SPACE or whatever you have as a keyboard combo for it, and peruse your options. In contrast to `get`-less getters where you have no idea what's available. "A method that returns something other than void and takes no params" isn't good enough. After all, e.g. `file.delete()` is that: It returns non-void (it returns `boolean`), and has no params. Yet, that is __definitely not a getter__.